# How to make the error = false appear in Fractal json response

Tags: json, laravel-5, dingo-api

I'm using Fractal [transformer](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/) to prettify my User model json return (using Laravel 5.3 + dingo api).

Previously I was returning my user model like this:

```
    return response()->success(compact('user'));
```

and the json was returned like this

```
{
    "errors": false,
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "
```

Now I use a transformer, and return it like this:

```
    return $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer);
```

and the json looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Client",
        "last_name": "Testing",
```

How do I wire things up with fractal to return the same structure as it was previously? All my unit tests expect the original format, and so they're failing like this:

```
1) LoginEmailTest::testLoginEmailSuccess
Unable to find JSON fragment
["errors":false]
within
[{"data":[{"user":{"a
```

## Update

I think the obvious place to customize the response is in the Fractal default [dataArraySerializer](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal/blob/master/src/Serializer/DataArraySerializer.php). But I'm not sure how to deal with the error parameter, in other words, how do I pass it an actual error if it exists rather than just hardcoded it to null?

Answer (score 0):

so this is how i fixed it (but for some reason I'm not happy with this whole situation, being a laravel nuub yet having familiarity with rails/django etc.. something doesn't feel right about all of this:)

```
<?php
/*
 * This is to address the problem asked here:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669423/how-to-make-the-error-false-appear-in-fractal-json-response 
*  basically we must add an error key to the top level of the json response
 *
 *
 */
namespace App\Http\Serializer;
use League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer;
class DataErrorArraySerializer extends ArraySerializer
{
    /**
     * Serialize a collection.
     *
     * @param string $resourceKey
     * @param array  $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return ['data' => $data, 'errors' => false];
    }
    /**
     * Serialize an item.
     *
     * @param string $resourceKey
     * @param array  $data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        return ['data' => $data, 'errors' => false];
    }
    /**
     * Serialize null resource.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function null()
    {
        return ['data' => [], 'errors' => false];
    }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
    $manager = new Manager();
    $manager->setSerializer(new DataErrorArraySerializer());
    $resource = new Item($user, new UserTransformer);
    return $manager->createData($resource)->toArray();
```

so this is what it looks like in a successful http request:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Client",
        "last_name": "Testing",
        ..

    },
    "errors": false
}
```

when an http error happens, it doesn't even execute that code anyways, it will return an error response (for example see this part of the code:

```
    } catch (\JWTException $e) {
        \Log::debug('Could not create token for login email: '. $email);
        return response()->error(trans('errors.no_token'), 500);
    }
```

and response is defined in public/index.php like so:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();
```

anyways again this is what an error looks like:

```
{
    "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
    "errors": {
        "message": [
            "The email must be a valid email address."
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 422
}
```